# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I need help understanding this bundler error message:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    metainspector (= 5.4.1) was resolved to 5.4.1, which depends on
      faraday-http-cache (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
        faraday (~> 0.8)

    metainspector (= 5.4.1) was resolved to 5.4.1, which depends on
      faraday_middleware (~> 0.11) was resolved to 0.11.0.1, which depends on
        faraday (< 1.0, >= 0.7.4)

    instagram-continued (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      faraday (~> 0.9.2)

    metainspector (= 5.4.1) was resolved to 5.4.1, which depends on
      faraday (~> 0.11)

    sendgrid-ruby (= 1.1.6) was resolved to 1.1.6, which depends on
      faraday (~> 0.9)
```

Maybe I’m not understanding it correctly, but I don’t see where the issue is with `faraday`. All these dependencies seem to require a `faraday` version greater or equal than 0.7.4 but less than 1.0. My current version is 0.9.2. I've always understood the `~>` pointer to indicate `greater than or equal to`. Is that incorrect?

Here is the relevant portion of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'instagram-continued', '1.2.1', require: "instagram"
gem 'metainspector', '5.4.1'
```

Comment: Did u tried `bundle update` ? Or u can try to delete `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` that's what helped me with compatibility for gems.

Comment: Yes, makes no difference.

Comment: Check if there's no confusion between versions `gem list` (u can have multiple versions), then I would take a look if the current Rails/Ruby version is compatible with `faraday` gem.

Comment: According to `gem list` I only have a single version of `faraday` installed - `0.9.2`. I also only have the latest versions installed of the other gems from my Gemfile that I listed above.

Comment: Last time I had `faraday` gem on Rails 4, if u are running Rails 5 it could be possible that the gem is not ready yet.

Comment: I'm on Rails 4.2.7.1

Comment: My last idea is to remove gem and try different version.. If that doesn't help, not sure what else can cause that problem..

Comment: Unfortunately I need these exact versions so downgrading isn't an option. Upgrading isn't an option either since the versions I need are already the latest...